# html2canvas: text overlaps occasionally

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to take an image of DOM element and then use it in pdf presentation. Im using `html2canvas` library for rendering DOM elements into canvas and then into image (dataUrl).

9/10 times it works fine and im happy with the result, but sometimes there is an annoying glitch that you can see below

Glitch:

[image]

No glitch:

[image]

As you can see in the first image, words are overlapping.

Is there any way to avoid such glitches when using html2canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding fonts to `iframe` that `html2canvas` creates for rendering. Like so:

```
// get font faces from original document
const fonts = document.fonts;

html2canvas(node, {
  onclone: (document) => {
    // add fonts to html2canvas's iframe
    fonts.forEach(font => {
      document.fonts.add(font)
    })
  }
})
```

Dont know exactly why this works, but it is;)